# If $a_{ij}=|f(i)~g(j)|, A=[a_{ij}]_{n\times n}$, then $\operatorname{Tr} (A^k)=(\operatorname{Tr}(A))^k,n,k \in I^+$

Tags: matrices, trace

Let $f(i)$ and $g(j)$ be real and finite valued functions of positive integers $i$ and $j$, my numerical experiments suggest that
If $$a_{ij}=|f(i)~g(j)|, A=[a_{ij}]_{n\times n}, \text{then}~~ Tr (A^k)=(Tr(A))^k,n,k \in I^+$$
I would like to see a proof for this observation, exceptions may also be pointed out.

I have tried all elementary transcendental and algebraic functions for $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $A = f g^T$ with vectors $f, g \in \Bbb R^n$. Therefore is
$$
 A^k = f (g^T f)^{k-1} g^T = (g^T f)^{k-1} \cdot f g^T
 = \left(\sum_{j=1}^n f_j g_j \right)^{k-1} \cdot f g^T
$$
since $g^T f$ is a scalar. It follows that
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(A^k)
= \left(\sum_{j=1}^n f_j g_j \right)^{k-1} \operatorname{Tr}(f g^T)
= \left(\sum_{j=1}^n f_j g_j \right)^k \, ,
$$
confirming your observation.

The fact that the entries are real-valued and non-negative is not needed, the same is true for real- or complex-valued vectors $f, g$, or for vectors in any commutative field $\Bbb K$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks Martin.